# Fitting data with heaviside step function

Tags: matlab, function, curve-fitting

I have some code to fit data to heaviside function. However, the fitting routine is not working properly. It varies so much dependent on the initial conditions and cant find the minimum. Can someone help? I have pasted the code below, the sample script and attached the file with the y-data.

```
ydata=[10 8 12 8 14 9 11 10 200 210 190 190 201 205 203 206 185 30 28 32 35 28 33 29];  
n=length(ydata);
xdata=[1:n];

%function
predicted = @(a,xdata) a(1)*heaviside(xdata-a(2))-a(3)*heaviside(xdata-a(4));

%initial conditions
a0 = [10;8;200;18];

% Fit model to data.
[ahat,resnorm,residual,exitflag,output,lambda,jacobian]=lsqcurvefit(predicted,a0,xdata,ydata);

% Plot fit with data.
plot(xdata,ydata);   

%plot fits
opts = fitoptions( 'Method', 'NonlinearLeastSquares');

%plot fit function
fitfinal = ahat(1)*heaviside(xdata-ahat(2))-ahat(3)*heaviside(xdata-ahat(4));

hold on 
plot(xdata,fitfinal)
hold off
```

In the end I would like to extract the lengths of the horizontal sections.

Comment: MATLAB or Python?

Comment: Also, format your code properly please

Comment: The code is in Matlab.

Answer (score 2):

This is a trivial function to fit. Simply look for the two places where there is a big jump:

```
plot(ydata)
hold on

dy = abs(diff(ydata));
[~,index] = sort(dy,'descend');

% First segment = 1:index(1)
m = mean(ydata(1:index(1)));
plot([1,index(1)],[m,m])

% Second segment = index(1)+1:index(2)
m = mean(ydata(index(1)+1:index(2)));
plot([index(1)+1,index(2)],[m,m])

% Third segment = index(2)+1:length(ydata)
m = mean(ydata(index(2)+1:length(ydata)));
plot([index(2)+1,length(ydata)],[m,m])
```

As a "fitted function" I've plotted the segments using the mean of the function across those samples, but all the information is there to compose a function using two Heaviside functions.

Also, I've taken `xdata` implicitly as the indices. But you can make that explicit also if your sample locations are irregular.

Comment: Thanks  @Cris Luengo. Seems to work. But the procedure seems affected if there are one of two points more in the section where there is a big drop. such as y=[10 8 12 8 14 9 11 10 200 210 205 200 198 201 205 203 206 185 120 50 30 28 32 35 28 33 29];

Comment: What do you expect the result to be in this case? Right now it takes the 120 point to be part of the right segment, which might not be correct. Do you want the separation to be at the 120, rather than in between samples? Do you want to fit an error function to the drop, rather than a Heaviside function? If you're working with band-limited signals, that would be a better approach anyway.

Comment: Yeah maybe an error function  to the drop would do the trick. The general problem is that when there are some points between the drop, the difference between points will be less and this might lead to the big drop not being fully recognized as such. Identifying the steps using slopes might be a more refined approach. But thanks again for the solution you provided.